# How would you reduce this array? (Read description for more info)

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinatorics

My mind is boggled, maybe because i've been stuck on this issue for a bit.

I have an array (redacted for readability):

```
variants = [
 {title: 'color', children: [{title: 'red'}, {title: 'blue'}]
 {title: 'size', children: [{title: 'large'}] 
]
```

But need the following output:

```
variants = [ 
 'color/red/size/large',
 'color/blue/size/large',

]
```

or if the initial array is:

```
variants = [
 {title: 'color', children: [{title: 'red'}, {title: 'blue'}]
 {title: 'size', children: [{title: 'large'}, {title: 'medium'}] 
]
```

the new array would be:

```
variants = [ 
 'color/red/size/large',
 'color/blue/size/large',
 'color/red/size/medium',
 'color/blue/size/medium',
]
```

Comment: This looks more like combinatorics than reduction to me

Comment: Have you tried  anything yet if yes can you post that ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts interesting. never heard of the term. i'm assuming the reduce method would still need to be used?

Comment: @Dileet `.reduce()` could work, but I think more readable approaches would not use it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts would you be able to give me an example with my use case? I guess you're thinking more of a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly succinct reduce, but it has a nested `flatMap(() => map())` call in its midst so I can't vouch for its efficiency.

```js
const variants = [
  { title: 'color', children: [{ title: 'red' }, { title: 'blue' }] },
  { title: 'size', children: [{ title: 'large' }, { title: 'medium' }] },
]

variants.sort((a, b) => b.children.length - a.children.length);

const out = variants.reduce((acc, { title, children }) => {
  const props = children.map(({ title: child }) => `${title}/${child}`);
  acc = acc.length === 0 ? props : acc.flatMap(a => props.map(p => `${a}/${p}`));
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(out)
```